# Android - Add custom layout to popup menu item

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

I've been working at this now for a while. I'm trying to create a PopupMenu whose top most item looks different then all the rest of the items - essentially a header item that contains a title.

I've tried setting an android:actionLayout for that item, linking that particular item to an xml file that should generate the desired layout. However, this seems to have absolutely no effect. From there I tried to set the actionView programmatically - creating a custom view and then setting it to the item. Still no effect.

I've done research here on SO and looked a at least 10 tutorials; maybe I just suck at Googling today, but I cannot find a way to do this.

Here was my last attempt:

```
// * my_menu.xml
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group 
        android:id="@+id/menu_title_group" >
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/menu_title_item"
            android:title=""
            app:actionLayout="@layout/popup_menu_title_header_layout" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

And then...

```
// * popup_menu_title_header_layout.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/popup_menu_title_header_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

And then...

```
    // * ShowPopupMenu.Activity
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), showMenuButton);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_title_item).setTitle(some_dynamic_string);
    popup.getMenu().add(1,0,0,"some_dynamic_option_title_1");
    popup.getMenu().add(1,1,0,"some_dynamic_option_title_2");
```

... the popup menu appears exactly as expected, however the top item is not effected at all by the actionLayout. Note that I tried using app:actionLayout, as suggested by some. Also note, I do not want to use a context menu for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm... perhaps not working because this PopupMenu is NOT in the ActionBar - it's anchored to a standard Button.

Comment: Likely going to have to use ListPopupWindow - PopupMenu doesn't seem to be very flexible in terms of customization...

Comment: using popup instead of ContextMenu?

Comment: I second using `PopUpWindow` if customisation is required

Answer (score 0):

use the same context of actionBar to create the PopupMenu

```
actionBar.getThemedContext()
```

So,

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity)     getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
  PopupMenu popMenu = new PopupMenu(actionBar.getThemedContext(), anyView);
```